# NativeBase unable to list only some part of array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

So my data is:

```
[
  {"id_categories":1,"name":"One"},
  {"id_categories":2,"name":"Two"},
  {"id_categories":3,"name":"Three"}
]
```

And my class to display the list is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Body, Left, 
         Right, List, ListItem, } from 'native-base';

export default class ListData extends Component {
    render(){

        let articles = this.props.data.map(function(items, index){
            return(
            <List dataArray={items}
                renderRow={(item) =>
                  <ListItem>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>   // this displays the id also
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>   // this does not display anything
                    //Only using one of the two <Text> above at a time
                  </ListItem>
                }>
            </List>
          )
        });

        return(
        <Content>
            {articles}
        </Content>      

        )
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to be able to show only the `name` in the list and make it TouchableOpacity and pass the value of the `id_categories` clicked to another screen. But I'm not able to show the only the `name`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You don't need to map your array if you use native base list
dataArray contains your array data and renderrow contains a component or custom component.

```
return (
    <List dataArray={this.props.data}
      renderRow={(item) =>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>  
        </ListItem>
      }>
    </List>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `item` inside `map` function is already the one you want to process: `{"id_categories":1,"name":"One"}`.

So inside the `map` loop you can access `name` by `item.name` as follow:

```html
let articles = this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
  // item ={"id_categories":1,"name":"One"},
  return(
    <List dataArray={"I will skip this one"}
      renderRow={(item) =>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </ListItem>
      }>
    </List>
  )
});
```

**EDIT**

Just have a look at `NativeBase` `List`, and I think this should fit your requirements

```html
let articles = (
    <List dataArray={this.props.data}
        renderRow={(item) => <ListItem><Text>{item.name}</Text></ListItem>}>
    </List>
  )
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `dataArray={"I will skip this one"}` shall I make it an empty object? Or not to mention the `dataArray`?

Comment: Because inside `map` function, `item` is not an `Array`. I don't know if it fits your purpose. However, it should be `this.props.data` if I understand your code correctly

Comment: I'm mapping `articles` so I can return it. If that makes sense.